# How use variables from AsciiDoc in PlantUML diagrams?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, plantuml

I'm using `AsciidocFX` for creating documentation. Variables created in `asciidoc` need to be replaced in diagrams. An example which doesn't work:

```
== My title
:parent-class: Parent
:child-class: Child

[plantuml,"class-inheritence",svg,subs=attributes+]
....
class {parent-class}
class {child-class}
{parent-class} <|-- {child-class}
....
```

Instead of class diagram, following result is shown. What is wrong?

[image]

Comment: any advance with this?

Answer (score 1):

When I paste your Asciidoc snippet into [Eclipse Asciidoctor Editor](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/asciidoctor-editor) (v2.4.1) there is absolutely nothing wrong with your code (see next picture).
*Just a note: I am the author of the mentioned eclipse plugin.*

Looking at your error message, the problem seems to be not at Asciidoctor level but on `plantuml`: Those error info pictures are generated by `plantuml.jar` when it comes to errors.

An option is, that `AsciidoctorFX` (or the installed/used Asciidoctor version) does not replace the place holders (parent-class, child-class) correctly and just give plantuml the plain, unchanged plantuml code - looking at the error message this looks very likely to be the problem.

So I think `AsciidoctorFX` uses an incompatible or outdated `plantuml` version or an old Asciidoctor version (or you have installed an old one and AsciidoctorFX is using this).

Maybe you can just update your `AsciidoctorFX` installation or the used Asciidoctor installation? If this is not helping, you could add an issue at https://github.com/asciidocfx/AsciidocFX/issues so it can be fixed by the maintainers.

[image: Pasted code into eclipse asciidoctor editor plugin]